# "There is" at the end of a sentence

Tags: there-is

In an english-learning magazine there is a sentence like *"Tourism is the biggest industry **There is**."*

It is the first time i have seen "there is" at the end of a sentence. Is it correct and means something like *"it is the biggest industry in the world"* or is it just a mistake?.

Comment: Your interpretation is right. It's a declarative content clause with the subordinator omitted, cf. "Tourism is the biggest industry (that) there is."

Comment: Have you noted the details under the tag "there-is"? Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Tourism is the biggest industry there is."
(Noun phrase + BE + (superlative) complement + there is)

Yes, it is indeed correct English syntax.

It means "in existence [today]" or "of its kind" or "I know (of)" or "available" or "at hand"

"[someone] is the [...] person (there is) to ask about grammar."

You can see that it is optional, but do you also see that if we use it, it sounds a more modest expression than "in the world".

After all, isn't everyone (that we know) "in the world" assuming they are alive?  :-)

Comment: See my comment at OP.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/14666/kris  Why?

Comment: This: "Have you noted the details under the tag "there-is"? Does it help?" -- not my profile!